# Android json parsing JSONEXCEPTION

Tags: android, json

I got responseString from server, but when I put into JSONObject, there is an error: JSONException

My Json String is below (what I exactly got from server!)

```
  [
{
    "myregID": "APA91bHjhw8w_wo6eQOyhrtgx0w8Uypv-oxck28mRP3nfgmg0DFhRvfzpBNHncea7-YrxFV46-_8WVK2UQDXrk6_qqwtHnYlh63P-jobKfGaBi3khnGZ0q-mTLMmWc5ylnv1IcdVYFFRTQqK6oYjEz8BgP_JcxiJ9A",


    "yourregID": "APA91bGuEcXeUwMl5PE74JB2KoVSsrYllQl4M0Pil6nPsTCBbMSngriODDLvpcDBgKY1sYj-4NiW8upgLb1VAPf2sgF5ZhUYg2Usdabg-s6CYRVJJBpDFX4MVvOUJ09pbb1lZsBuA6krXJ9CFSTdRBqyoPQid6zYKg"
}
  ]
```

And my android Client Code is below about that.

```
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
     tmp_myregID = jsonObject.getString("myregID");
     Log.v("3333","1111");
     tmp_yourregID = jsonObject.getString("yourregID");
```

code flow stops at `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to fetch the array `[...]` then the object `{...}` :

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    Log.e(TAG, jsonObject.getString("myregID"));
    Log.e(TAG, jsonObject.getString("yourregID"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your Json root element is a JsonArray and not a Json Object, so get a JsonArray first.